# r - How to expand data.frame over unused factor levels?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I need to do this for a list of dataframes that all have a common variable. I want to expand each dataframe so that they would have the common variable expanded to all of the levels present in all of the dataframes.

```
myList <- list(A = data.frame(A1 = rnorm(10), A2 = rnorm(10), A3 = rnorm(10),
                              year = factor(c(2000:2009))),
               B = data.frame(B1 = rnorm(10), B2 = rnorm(10), B3 = rnorm(10),
                              year = factor(c(2001:2010))))

masterYear <- unique(unlist(lapply(myList, function(x) levels(x$year)), use.names = F))
```

I've thus far tried to use dplyr and tidyr packages in a function

```
funExpand <- function(x){
         levels(x$year) <- c(levels(x$year), setdiff(masterYear, levels(x$year)))
         vars <- names(x)[-length(names(x))]
         x %>%
              tidyr::complete_(x, c(vars), fill = list(0))
         x
}

myList2 <- lapply(myList, funExpand)
```

But that yields an error. I've tried various combinations of tidyr::complete and tidyr::complete_ functions (first argument x or year?), all yielding some error. That tells me that I'm not interpreting the complete functions correctly.

Aside fixes for this error, I also welcome all suggestions for improving the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated to reflect comment by OP**

Try this,

```
myList2 <- lapply(myList, 
                  function(db) {
                    db$year <- factor(as.character(db$year), levels=masterYear)
                    merge(db, data.frame(year=setdiff(masterYear, db$year)), all=T)
                  })
```

The new rows will have `NA`, if you really need them to be `0` add another line `db[is.na(db)] <- 0` in the function.

Comment: Thanks. I need the year columns in all dfs to have union of all years found in all dfs with zero values when not present in that particular df. Unfortunately your suggestion doesn't do it.

Comment: @Antti I have updated by answer based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't need `x %>%`

```
funExpand <- function(x) {levels(x$year) <- c(levels(x$year), 
                                  setdiff(masterYear, levels(x$year)))
                           vars <- names(x)[-length(names(x))]
                           complete_(x, vars, fill=list(0))}
lapply(myList, funExpand)
```

Comment: That could be true. I started with some example found via googling that piped tidyr::expand and dplyr::left_join - complete does both. However, I could not make it work the way you suggest.

Comment: @Antti My solution was based on the code you used and the error you showed.

Comment: I appreciate it! Nevertheless, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Antti As I said, I am only correcting the error.  As per your previous comment,  you already got the other function names.  I certainly don't think about other functions when the code is about `complete`

Comment: Fair enough. In that case a comment in stead of a full answer would have been appropriate. IMHO.

Comment: @Antti I had no reason to think that you were looking for another function.  The question was about `complete` and why the error occured.